# Twitter authentication credentials

Tags: twitter, social-networking, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am new to the social network analysis and twitter API.I wanted to collect tweets on certain topic .So i have written the following code

```
package com;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Tweet;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;

public class TwitterSearchAdvance {
    public static void main(String[] vishal) throws TwitterException,
            IOException {
        // List<Tweet> Data = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
        StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

        for (int page = 0; page <= 4; page++) {
            Query query = new Query("Airtel");
            // query.setRpp(100); // 100 results per page

            QueryResult qr = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> qrTweets = qr.getTweets();
            System.out.println("-------------------" + qrTweets.size());
            // break out if there are no more tweets

            for (Status t : qrTweets) {
                System.out.println(t.getCreatedAt() + ": " + t.getText());

                stringbuffer.append(t);
                stringbuffer.append("\n");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                        "/home/vishal/FirstDocu.txt"), true));
                bw.write(stringbuffer.toString());
                bw.newLine();
                // bw.write(t.getCreatedAt() + ": " + t.getText());
                bw.close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run the following program the following error starts coming

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/configuration.html for the detail.
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:200)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1833)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:282)
    at com.TwitterSearchAdvance.main(TwitterSearchAdvance.java:28)
```

Where do i need to provide credentials in my program

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the options here http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html

There are a number of ways to provide credentials to your program:

1. Properties File
2. ConfigurationBuilder class
3. System properties
4. Environment Variables

All details and instructions can be found in the link